# how to move element with arrow using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm still learning JS and I'm trying to move this div with arrows using Javascript but it moves only 1 step per click can someone please help me how to make it moves more steps

check my code please

```js
let
div = document.getElementById("test");

function move(e){

    if(e.keyCode ==40){
        div.style.top = 10+"px"
    }

    if(e.keyCode ==38){
div.style.top = -10+"px"    }



    if(e.keyCode==39){
        div.style.left = 10 +"px"
    }

    if(e.keyCode==37){
        div.style.left = -10 +"px"
    }
    

}

window.onkeydown = move;
```

```css
div{

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="test"></div>

<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've done well so far. All you have to do is get the current position from the target element (`e.target`) and add/subtract `10` to that current position for each key code. You should know that `.keyCode` is deprecated (you shouldn't use it anymore). Instead, use `.code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, you need the current position

I use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

You might also look at [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code/code_values) instead of keyCode

```js
const div = document.getElementById("test");

function move(e) {
  const pos = div.getBoundingClientRect()
  let top = pos.top;
  let left = pos.left;
  const code = e.code;
  
  switch (code) {
    case "ArrowRight": left += 10; break;
    case "ArrowLeft" : left -= 10; break;
    case "ArrowUp"   : top  -= 10; break;
    case "ArrowDown" : top  += 10; break;
  }  
  div.style.top = `${top}px`;
  div.style.left = `${left}px`;
}

window.addEventListener("keydown",move);
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I updated the code to something more modern

Comment: Thank you sir ❤ it took me some time to understand what you have did with the code

Answer (score -1):

You can save the current position then move it again, set an offset and add/remove distance at every keydown

```js
const div = document.getElementById("test");
let position = 0
const offset = 10;

function move(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    position += offset;
    div.style.top = position + "px"
  }

  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    position -= offset;
    div.style.top = position + "px"
  }

  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    position += offset;
    div.style.left = position + "px"
  }

  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    position -= offset;
    div.style.left = position + "px"
  }
}

document.onkeydown = move;
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="test"></div>

  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is no better than the other answer saving the position. Getting the position from the element is much safer. If the position is not 10px (from where?)  then this code will see the div jump on the first kepress

Answer (score -3):

You are setting its offset to a fixed value of 10 or -10.

You need to store the current position somehow and offset the new position based on the current one.

```
//Intiate once at the beginning of the script
let currentVerticalPosition = 0;

if(e.keyCode ==40){
    currentVerticalPosition += 10;
    div.style.top = currentVerticalPosition +"px";
}
```

Comment: vertical is fine but what about horizontal positon